# Getting data from Listview with BaseAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview, adapter

I've an activity(A) that has a `Button` and when the user press it, it will add an `Object` to `static List`. I've another activity(B) that has a `ListView` to show the content of the static list. In the activity(B) I want to use the attribute of an object that is stored in that static list in the specific row. How can I do that? My code is shown below:

```
//Activity (A):
Send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
...
//  Add to mycaseList
All_Static.MyCaseList.add(case1);
...
}});

//==============================================================================

//Activity (B):

public class MyPage extends Activity {

     boolean returnvar ;
    private Activity mContext;
    Button createForm;
    Button ConfExpandRegion, Cancelb;
    String ExpandMsg, CancelMsg;
    boolean b;
    MyCaseClass mycase;
    TextView tvCase;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;

    //for list
    ListView list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mypage);


        // Moving to another activity
        createForm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.creat_new_formbtn);
        createForm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent j = new Intent(MyPage.this, CreateNewForm.class);
                startActivity(j);

            }
        });

        // ============================================================================================
        // for list


            list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mypage_list);
            list.setClickable(true);

            final List<MyCaseClass> listOfMyCases = new ArrayList<MyCaseClass>();

            MyCasesListAdapter adapter = new MyCasesListAdapter(this, listOfMyCases, MyPage.this);

            for (MyCaseClass m : All_Static.getMyCaseList())
                adapter.add(new MyCaseClass(m));

            // after fill the adapter.. assign the list to the adapter
            list.setAdapter(adapter);


            list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long index) {


                }
            });

        // ========================================================================================

    }



    public void sendSMS(String number, String msg) throws Exception {
        if (!b) {
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, msg, null, null);
        }
        b = true;
    }

    // ========================================================================

    public void ShowingDialogExpand(){
        final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Conformation");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to Expand Report Region?");
        alertDialog.setButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                   ExpandMsg = "Case_ID expand";
                   if (!b) {
                        try {
                            // Should write server number here + the chatting must be pushed above 
                            sendSMS("0000", ExpandMsg);
                            Toast.makeText(MyPage.this, "Request Sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            Toast.makeText(MyPage.this, e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    }
                   //ConfExpandRegion.setEnabled(false);
               }

            });

            alertDialog.setButton2("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // here you can add functions
                // Do nothing 




               }
            });

            alertDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
            alertDialog.show();
    }

    public void  ShowingDialogCancel(int i){
        final AlertDialog alertDialog2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        alertDialog2.setTitle("Conformation?");
        alertDialog2.setMessage("Are you sure you want to cancel x cases?");

        String str = "ID:" + i;
        Toast.makeText(MyPage.this, str , 0)
        .show();
        alertDialog2.setButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public  void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                     CancelMsg = "Case_ID cancel";
                     returnvar=true;

                   if (!b) {
                        try {
                            // Should write server number here + the chatting must be pushed above 
                            sendSMS("0000", CancelMsg);
                            Toast.makeText(MyPage.this, "Cancelation request sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            Toast.makeText(MyPage.this, e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    }
                   }
            });

            alertDialog2.setButton2("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // here you can add functions
                // Do nothing 
                   returnvar = false;
                   Toast.makeText(MyPage.this, "inside No", 0)
                    .show();


               }
            });

            alertDialog2.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
            alertDialog2.show();

    }

}


//=================================================================================

// My BaseAdapter 
public class MyCasesListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private MyPage myPage;
    private List<MyCaseClass> listOfCases;
    private Activity parentActivity;

    // TODO test
    MyCaseClass entry;

    // TODO delete it not imp.
    public MyCasesListAdapter() {

        super();

    }

    public MyCasesListAdapter(MyPage mypage, List<MyCaseClass> listOfCaseParameter, Activity parentActivity) {
        this.myPage = mypage;
        this.listOfCases = listOfCaseParameter;
        this.parentActivity = parentActivity;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return listOfCases.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listOfCases.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

         entry = listOfCases.get(position);
         //this.getitem(position)
        if (convertView == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) myPage
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mypage_row, null);
          }


        // this is row items..
        // Set the onClick Listener on this button
        Button ConfExpandRegion = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.expand);
        Button Cancelb = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cancelCase);
        TextView tvCase = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mypage_name);

        // To be a clickable button
        ConfExpandRegion.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        ConfExpandRegion.setFocusable(false);


        ConfExpandRegion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                myPage.ShowingDialogExpand();
            }
        });

        // To be a clickable button
        Cancelb.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        Cancelb.setFocusable(false);
        Cancelb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                entry = (MyCaseClass) v.getTag();
                int caseid= entry.getID();
                myPage.ShowingDialogCancel(caseid);

                Toast.makeText(myPage, "inside calling", 0).show();

                //MyCaseClass entry = (MyCaseClass) v.getTag();
                //listOfCases.remove(entry);

                // listPhonebook.remove(view.getId());
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        // Set the entry, so that you can capture which item was clicked and
        // then remove it
        // As an alternative, you can use the id/position of the item to capture
        // the item
        // that was clicked.
        ConfExpandRegion.setTag(entry);
        Cancelb.setTag(entry);

        // btnRemove.setId(position);

        return convertView;
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        MyCaseClass entry = (MyCaseClass) view.getTag();
        listOfCases.remove(entry);
        // listPhonebook.remove(view.getId());
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    private void showDialog(MyCaseClass entry) {
        // Create and show your dialog
        // Depending on the Dialogs button clicks delete it or do nothing
    }

    public void add(MyCaseClass myCaseClass) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        listOfCases.add(myCaseClass);
    }



}
//===========================================================================
// StaticClass
public class All_Static {

    public static List<MyCaseClass> MyCaseList = new ArrayList<MyCaseClass>();

    public static List<MyCaseClass> getMyCaseList() {
        return MyCaseList;
    }

    public static void setMyCaseList(List<MyCaseClass> myCaseList) {
        MyCaseList = myCaseList;
    }

    //===========================================================================
    public static List<HelpersClass> HelperList = new ArrayList<HelpersClass>();

    public static List<HelpersClass> getHelperList() {
        return HelperList;
    }

    public static void setHelperList(List<HelpersClass> helperList) {
        HelperList = helperList;
    }


}
```

Comment: I don't know if I understand your question, but if you want to pass an Object from activity A to activity B here is one approach from [How to pass object from one activity to another in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736389/how-to-pass-object-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Serialize your Object and pass it to activity B while calling it through intent

Comment: but i do not need to transfer the whole object, i just need to get data from a specific row in arrayList 
thanks

Comment: What kind of arrayList you are using? Like is it String, int or some of your own class object?

Comment: ArrayList of Object, I want to retrieve the name of the object and show it in side TextView in the row of the list by using tv.setText(object.getName());  when I did that it retrieve a null value !!! :\

Comment: You can use singleton class to save your list and you can access it in different activities.

Comment: Actually my arraylist is static !!

Comment: Its always better to use mvc architecture. So my advice would be to keep your data separated from your views. It should not be binded to a particular view.

Comment: but I've to show the user the name of the case in specific row, I'm working on my Graduation project well, this is a requirement :|