# Removing a row in ListView [android Application]

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

How can I delete a row in listview after pressing YES button from alertDialog buttons?!

in my code `Cancel` is a button in row I want if i press it, it should do two things:

1. Show me alertDialog : i did that by calling a function `ShowDialogCancel()` ,
2. After pressing: YES in this alertDialog ==> the row should be removed !!

I tried with many ways but it delete the row before I press YES button in the alertDialog

any Suggestion

Monerah ...

My adapter class:

```
public class MyCasesListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private MyPage myPage;
    private List<MyCaseClass> listOfCases;
    private Activity parentActivity;

    // TODO test
    MyCaseClass entry;

    // TODO delete it not imp.
    public MyCasesListAdapter() {

        super();

    }

    public MyCasesListAdapter(MyPage mypage, List<MyCaseClass> listOfCaseParameter, Activity parentActivity) {
        this.myPage = mypage;
        this.listOfCases = listOfCaseParameter;
        this.parentActivity = parentActivity;
    }
...
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

         entry = listOfCases.get(position);
         //this.getitem(position)
        if (convertView == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) myPage
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mypage_row, null);
          }


        // this is row items..
        // Set the onClick Listener on this button
        Button ConfExpandRegion = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.expand);
        Button Cancelb = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cancelCase);
        TextView tvCase = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.mypage_name);

        // To be a clickable button
        ConfExpandRegion.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        ConfExpandRegion.setFocusable(false);


        ConfExpandRegion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                myPage.ShowingDialogExpand();
            }
        });

        // To be a clickable button
        Cancelb.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        Cancelb.setFocusable(false);
        Cancelb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                entry = (MyCaseClass) v.getTag();
                int caseid= entry.getID();
                myPage.ShowingDialogCancel(caseid);

                Toast.makeText(myPage, "inside calling", 0).show();

                //MyCaseClass entry = (MyCaseClass) v.getTag();
                //listOfCases.remove(entry);

                // listPhonebook.remove(view.getId());
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        // Set the entry, so that you can capture which item was clicked and
        // then remove it
        // As an alternative, you can use the id/position of the item to capture
        // the item
        // that was clicked.
        ConfExpandRegion.setTag(entry);
        Cancelb.setTag(entry);

        // btnRemove.setId(position);

        return convertView;
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        MyCaseClass entry = (MyCaseClass) view.getTag();
        listOfCases.remove(entry);
        // listPhonebook.remove(view.getId());
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }


}
```

From my page class:

```
public void  ShowingDialogCancel(){
        final AlertDialog alertDialog2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        alertDialog2.setTitle("Conformation?");
        alertDialog2.setMessage("Are you sure you want to cancel x cases?");


        alertDialog2.setButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public  void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                     CancelMsg = "Case_ID cancel";


                   if (!b) {
                        try {
                            // Should write server number here + the chatting must be pushed above 
                            sendSMS("0000", CancelMsg);
                            Toast.makeText(MyPage.this, "Cancelation request sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            Toast.makeText(MyPage.this, e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    }
                   }
            });

            alertDialog2.setButton2("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // here you can add functions
                // Do nothing 

                   Toast.makeText(MyPage.this, "inside No", 0)
                    .show();


               }
            });

            alertDialog2.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
            alertDialog2.show();

    }

}
```

Comment: Start variable names in lower case, otherwise they are colored like class names (and by convention instance variable names starts in lowercase).

Answer (score 0):

How are you populating your listview? If you are using an array you can remove the data from your array and reload your list view.

Comment: in my Adapter class I put a code in Cancel button, that clear the list but i didn't work ... 


can you explain more =)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the position you want to remove, you can call

```
listOfCases.remove(position);
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: i did that and it removed it correctly, but I want this removing happened when the user press YES button in the AlertDialog

Comment: So put the code inside the `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` for the OK button of your dialog.

Comment: So get a reference to the adapter

Comment: can you tell me how can I do  that, my full code is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366126/getting-data-from-listview-with-baseadapter-android-application

Comment: I'm not sure what you need help with, are you new to programming?

Comment: yeah i'm newer in android :" and java

Answer (score 0):

Using the code you have, if you pass references to `ShowingDialogCancel(MyCasesListAdapter adapter, View view)` then you can add something like:

```
adapter.onClick(view);
```

to your "Yes" button.